# Visual Studio project generation

Tags: visual-studio-2013, project, code-generation, generator

Is there any way to auto generate visual studio projects with a, lets say, some kind of UML tool, so I can design project dependencies upfront and it will output the solution and its projects.

Bonus: I can do classical UML design (classes, interfaces, etc.) aswell

I'd appreciate any hint for any tool.

Comment: Visual Studio supports this with the Ultimate Version and Visio, and i think with 2013 also in build with the Architecture Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [GenMyModel](https://www.genmymodel.com). It lets you doing your model, writing and executing your own template generators directly from your browser.

Comment: As far as I can see there is project generation by default right? So I would need to write a template with generates the project file...

Comment: Yes, there is some sample generators, but not for visual project file as I know.